# Enable SignalR Trace in Windows Application

Tags: c#, signalr, desktop-application, trace

I tried to enable SignalR in a windows application following this link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/enabling-signalr-tracing
I have added the following configuration for bouth app.config I have in my solution.
It should work only in the project that uses SignalR I believe but it was not working so I have added the same block to app.config of main project also.
It is not working because I couldn't find the trace file server_traces.txt in anywhere.
I am not sure if it would be work just by adding this configuration or if is necessary to enable it on code.

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sharedListeners>
        <add name="traces" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="server_traces.txt" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <switches>
        <add name="SignalRSwitch" value="All" />
    </switches>
    <sources>
        <source name="SignalR.Connection">
            <listeners>
                <add name="traces" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="SignalR.PersistentConnection">
            <listeners>
                <add name="traces" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="SignalR.ReflectedHubDescriptorProvider">
            <listeners>
                <add name="traces" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="SignalR.HubDispatcher">
            <listeners>
                <add name="traces" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="SignalR.MessageBus">
            <listeners>
                <add name="traces" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport">
            <listeners>
                <add name="traces" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="SignalR.Transports.ServerSentEventsTransport">
            <listeners>
                <add name="traces" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="SignalR.Transports.ForeverFrameTransport">
            <listeners>
                <add name="traces" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="SignalR.Transports.LongPollingTransport">
            <listeners>
                <add name="traces" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat">
            <listeners>
                <add name="traces" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

And HubConnection trace is configured like this.

```
var tracePath = System.IO.Path.Combine("server_traces_{0}-{1}-{2}.txt", DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day));
var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(tracePath);
writer.AutoFlush = true;
hubConnection.TraceLevel = TraceLevels.All;
hubConnection.TraceWriter = writer;
```

I have put the name different from what is on app.config to be sure "server_trace.txt" to verify if that configuration is ignored, and it seems that is it. Isn't it needed ?

Comment: I Forgot to say this application is built on .NET  Framework 4.5

Comment: I missed the right configuration for path And it worked. 

But it seems that the configuration on App.config is ignored. I don't understand the reason.

Comment: Other problem that I have identified is many logs for OnMessages without any detailed information.

"10:50:20.4924078 - 75c41c7d-c07c-41ee-9008-46af84a7556a - WS: OnMessage({})"